# Performance using Spring RabbitMQ is slow

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I am trying to send a 51MB of data over 13 threads to another machine in a gap of 30 seconds. It means, at every 30 seconds, 51*13 = 663Mb of data is sent in a burst to the target machine.

### **Steps Followed:**

1. I have used shovels between the sender and the receiver rabbitmq server to transmit the messages.
2. Both sender and receiver have their own rabbitMq server running.
3. I am using RabbitTemplate.send(routingKey,51mbMessage) to send the message.
4. I am using OnMessageListener on the target machine to receive the messages.

### **OnMessageListener at Receiver side:**

```
<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory"          prefetch="10" >
    <rabbit:listener ref="onMessageReceiverforMyTestQueue"   queue- names="MyTestQueue" /> 
</rabbit:listener-container>

<bean id = "onMessageReceiverforLoadTestQueue"      class="MyPackage.MyMessageListener">
</bean>
```

### **ConnectionFactory at the receiver side:**

```
  class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg value="***.**.**.**"/>
    <property name="username" value="abcd"/>
    <property name="password" value="abcd"/>
    <property name="channelCacheSize" value="50"/>
```

### **Observations Made:**

1. The messages are taking lot of time to reach the target machine.I am getting delay of about 10-15 minutes.

Can you please help me in overcoming this delay. I would really appreciate any help offered here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to isolate the problem - for example, do you only see this with Spring AMQP? What happens if you generate similar load using the Java Client directly? Only then can you point the finger at Spring. Perhaps your network just can't handle the load.

Comment: What's your network setup?  E.g. hosted in a single AWS region, remotely on CloudAMQP, etc.?  That's often the biggest bottleneck.  Write a very simple script (no framework) to push large data sets to Rabbit and see if it can take the load quickly enough.

Comment: Hi, i understood the problem.. Unknowingly i was sending the same message back as acknowledgement. That means 51Mb message was sent and same 51mb message was sent back in the ackknowledgement message. This was resulting is choking of bandwidth which further led to slow throughput.  Thanks Gary and Matt for the time.